# How can I disable close on outside click for Chakra UI react Modal component?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm using a Chakra UI Modal in a React application. I want to disable closing the modal when the user clicks outside it, but I can't find any way to do it.

The documentation for the Chakra UI Modal is here: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/overlay/modal

There is no flag for `closeOnOutsideClick`

Comment: Never mind, there is a prop "closeOnOverlayClick" which, when set to false, disables modal closing when you click outside of it. Seems bleeding obvious in retrospect, and I thought I'd tested that prop, but I must have not done it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You can add `closeOnOverlayClick` prop to `<Modal>` component and set it to `false`:

```
function ManualClose() {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</Button>

      <Modal closeOnOverlayClick={false} isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          some content
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}
```

For your reference - https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/modal#close-modal-on-overlay-click